# Do preprocessor defines substitute in `operator""_name`

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor, user-defined-literals

Consider the following example provided by Aykhan Hagverdili:

```cpp
#include <string>

using std::operator""s;

#define s foobar

auto s = "hello world"s;
```

Some compilers would substitute `s` and fail compilation.
Some compilers would not substitute `s`.

See the result here: https://godbolt.org/z/jx4nhYczd
gcc fails, clang compiles

Which is right?

Comment: It would be easier if you gave examples of compilers that do the replacement or not. Also, identifier `_min` is [reserved](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) in global scope and you may not use it for macro (although using it for literal is fine) - that may or may not be the reason why some compilers do accept the code and others don't.

Comment: The `""_min` is one token.  It does not match the `_min` token.

Comment: Operator names not starting with `_` are reserved. Macro names starting with `_` are reserved. Thus, you have undefined behavior either way.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, good point. But operators are reserved for Standard Library. Assume it is a part of standard library implementation.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev Standard library implementations are implementation defined.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev Maybe you could bring one of the standard library operators into the global namespace with `using std::operator""s` and also define the `s` as a macro *after that* to make the question more meaningful.

Comment: Here's an example with what Ayxan suggested: https://godbolt.org/z/hs7M9P9c5. It's actually interesting, I think clang is right to compile this code, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Having a whitespace after `""` is deprecated in C++23. https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2521.html Implemenation status for this probably varies.

Comment: I say it all depends on the contents of `<cstddef>`.  Much of the content is implementation defined.  I would expect a  *nice* compiler to issue a warning if `min` was already in the symbol table before the `#define` is processed.  Remember that the preprocessor primarily builds a "new" version of the source code containing the substitution text.  The compiler and linker will determine which version of `min` to use.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev I would define the `s` macro *after* including the header.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, in this case the issue both compiler compile it. Looks like there's no standard-compliant way to have this problem.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili But then there's no ambiguity? `5s` is always interpreted as literal. On the other hand, if `""s` should compile with `#define s` beforehand is the question whether `""s` is one token or not. It seems that gcc treats it as two tokens.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev here you go: https://godbolt.org/z/jx4nhYczd

Comment: @Yksisarvinen see my previous comment.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, thanks, I pasted your example into the question

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Names starting with an underscore are reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace. Macto names do not belong to any namespace.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI In any case, you can't define a macro called `_min` because the implementation might have a global variable with that name and that variable might further be used in the definition of a standard macro, like `assert`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Then that implementation would have a bug I suppose. Why wouldn't it use a variable with a name that is reserved for all uses?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Well, it could have been used like `(::_min)`. Can you show me a case where this can go wrong?

Comment: Here's a follow up question about `#define _x`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76823547/are-you-allowed-to-define-min

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`"hello world"s` is, since C++11, a single preprocessing token matching the [*user-defined-string-literal*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex#nt:user-defined-string-literal) grammar production.

Macros substitute on the level of preprocessing tokens. Since there is no `s` preprocessing token, there can't be any substitution of your macro.

As a result your code is well-formed in C++14 or later. `std::operator""s` is chosen. In C++11 there was no `std::operator""s`.

However, before C++11 when user-defined literals were introduced, `"hello world"s` would have been two preprocessing tokens `"hello"` and `s`, so the latter one would have been substituted with your macro.

This is even explicitly mentioned in [[diff.cpp03.lex]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/diff.cpp03.lex#2) as a backwards-incompatible change with C++11.

Answer (score 3):

GCC is wrong.

A user-defined string literal like `"hello world"s` is a preprocessing-token, not two preprocessing-tokens `"hello world"` and `s`. The preprocessor should not replace parts of a preprocessing-token.